# ^C while process is doing an Lwt read

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-lwt, lwt

I'm working on a little program using `Lwt_io.read_into_exactly` and other functions from *Lwt_io*. It all works great, but **^C** (sigint) doesn't do anything, which forces me to kill -9 everytime I'm testing it, it's a bit annoying.

Is there something I should be doing to allow this to be killed normally by **^C**, maybe set the socket as non-blocking or something?

Thanks !

Comment: Could you post a little program demonstrating the problem?